# Discord.py Private Messages Bot

Tags: python, discord

In Discord.py how can I make my bot privately send messages to other people in a server. Like, if I want to message a person in the server who I have not friend requested yet, I can use this bot. I want it to use a slash command like
"/{user}{message}"
And the bot will display the message for them and make the user who it was sent to only see it.
How do I do this using discord.py?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the member and create a DM with them, then send whatever you want to the DM. See the following code:

```
member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id = (member id)) # could also use client.get_user(ID)
dm = await member.create_dm()
await dm.send('this will be sent to the user!')
```

Comment: @BuddyBob thanks for the feedback. I'll try to improve for next time.

Comment: Great to hear! If you'd like you can press the edit button underneath your answer and add your info.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to include more info.